# Validate daterangeinput to prevent end date is located before start date

Tags: r, shiny, date-range

I use **dateRangeInput** and want to prevent that the end date is before the starting date. For this I want to make use of **updateDateRangeInput**.

The following code ensures that the end date is 1 day after the starting date. But with my solution it is not possible to modify the end date afterwards. It always jumps to the day after the starting date.

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    dateRangeInput("Input_Dates", label = "Date", format = "DD dd-mm-yyyy", language = "en",
                                                  weekstart = 1, start = NULL, end = Sys.Date()+1)
  )

  shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$Input_Dates[1],{

      start_date <- input$Input_Dates[1]
      end_date <- start_date + 1

      updateDateRangeInput(session, "Input_Dates",
                           start = start_date,
                           end = end_date)
    })  
  })
}
```

How do I achieve that the end date in dateRangeInput automatically updates to the day after the starting day **and** I have the possibility to modify the end date afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
library(shiny)
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
maxdate <- Sys.Date()+1

if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    dateRangeInput("Input_Dates", label = "Date", format = "DD dd-mm-yyyy", language = "en",
                   weekstart = 1, start = NULL, end = maxdate,max = maxdate)
  )

  shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$Input_Dates[1],{

      start_date <- input$Input_Dates[1]
      end_date <- start_date + 1
      req(end_date <= maxdate)

      updateDateRangeInput(session, "Input_Dates",start = start_date,end = end_date)
    })  
  })
}
```

Comment: When I choose 2020-02-10 as starting date, it updates the end date to 2020-02-11, which is what I want. But I want furthermore, that I have the possibility to change the end date afterwards to e.g. 2020-02-15. In your code (like in my code) it is fixed to 2020-02-11.